# Numpy Where Multiple Conditions , cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do multiple conditions in a numpy where but getting the error: `cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]`

Here is the line:

```
d7['CAD'] = np.where(d7['Category'] == 'Stack' & d7['Currency'] == fxratetable['from_currency'],d7['CAD'] * fxratetable['fx_rate'], d7['CAD'])
```

All `dtypes` are `object` except for fx_rate which is `float64`.

Also another thought is that I am looking for one value with `Category = Stack` but looking for multiple values with my `Currency = from_currency`.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks.

### new error

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects now.
```

This is my new statement

```
d7['CAD'] = np.where((d7['Category'] == 'Stack') & 
                     (d7['Currency'] == fxratetable['from_currency']),
                     d7['CAD'] * fxratetable['fx_rate'], 
                     d7['CAD'])
```

d7:

```
+--------------+----------+----------+
| CAD          | Currency | Category |
+--------------+----------+----------+
| -4350242.355 | GBP      | Stack    |
+--------------+----------+----------+
| 424223.7584  | AUD      | Stack    |
+--------------+----------+----------+
```

fxratetable:

```
+---------------+---------+
| from_currency | fx_rate |
+---------------+---------+
| GBP           | 1.367   |
+---------------+---------+
| AUD           | 0.7706  |
+---------------+---------+
```

Expected new CAD column.

```
+----------------+
| CAD (expected) |
+----------------+
| -5948957.275   |
+----------------+
| 326991.5663    |
+----------------+
```

Comment: Wrap all comparisons, e.g. `==`, in `()`, so they are preformed before any of the `&` combinations.

Comment: hey im getting `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects` now.  This is my new statement `d7['CAD'] = np.where((d7['Category'] == 'Stack') & (d7['Currency'] == fxratetable['from_currency']),d7['CAD'] * fxratetable['fx_rate'], d7['CAD'])`

Comment: Have tested each input to the `np.where`?  Remember, python evaluates all function arguments before passing them in.  I suspect `d7['Currency'] == fxratetable['from_currency']` is the problem, but I don't have your dataframes to tests.  When debugging, break long expressions into pieces to better identify exactly where the problem is.

Comment: I put some sample data in,the question, hopefully this helps. Fyi there are more "Category";s and more "fx rates", I just decided to show two samples.

Comment: That doesn't help.  Did you test the expression I highlighted?

Comment: Yes your right, so this code actually ran fine : `d7['CAD'] = np.where(d7['Category'] == 'Stack',d7['CAD'] * 100, d7['CAD'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer `DataFrame.apply` when dealing with conditions.

```
d7['CAD'] = d7.apply(lambda row: row.CAD * fxratetable[fxratetable.from_currency == row.Currency].fx_rate.item() \
                                 if row.Category == 'Stack' else row.CAD, axis=1)
```

`fxratetable[fxratetable.from_currency == row.Currency]` selects the row in `fxratetable` that corresponds to the correct currency, `.fx_rate` selects the rate column, and `.item()` gives the number, instead of a Series.

You can see that only the `row.Category == 'Stack'` condition remains, the problematic Series comparison is now part of the selection.

And finally, `axis=1` is used to apply the function to DataFrame rows ([docu](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)).

I haven't tested this extensively, so let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for this ibd! however, did you just use shortforms for the dataframes? ie you used d instead of d7. Just trying to understand.

Comment: Sorry about that, when I tried it out I just changed d7 to d and fxratetable to f to make it easier. I've edited my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the second part of the Boolean expression. Presumably `d7` is more than just two rows, otherwise there wouldn't be this issue. `d7['Currency'] == fxratetable['from_currency']` compares the two series row-by-row, and when the rows run out of `fxratetable` it doesn't know what to compare `d7` to anymore.

I don't know if you are set on using NumPy or if there are limitations on what you can do, but a merge statement would handle this really easily:

```
# Merge the exchange rate
d7 = pd.merge(d7, fxratetable, left_on='Currency', right_on='from_currency', how='left')
# Find the rows which have a non-NaN exchange rate and multiply
d7['CAD'] = np.where(~np.isnan(d7['fx_rate']), d7['CAD']*d7['fx_rate'], d7['CAD'])
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this, but I need to only for Category = Stack, not for other cateories in D7. Also your first statement brings in fx table into my main d7 table? Does this just add to the existing table, I dont want to get rid of any rows of the main table(d7) with a join.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be what you expected. I've written it in a comprehensible way.

```
d7 = pd.DataFrame({'CAD':[-4350242.355,424223.7584],'Currency':['GBP','AUD'],'Category':['Stack','Stack']})
fxratetable = pd.DataFrame({'from_currency':['GBP','AUD'],'fx_rate':[1.367,0.7706 ]})
_condition1 = d7['Category'] == 'Stack'
_condition2 = d7['Currency'] == fxratetable['from_currency']
d7['CAD (expected)'] = np.where(_condition1 & _condition2,d7['CAD'] * fxratetable['fx_rate'],d7['CAD'])
d7
```

OUTPUT
[image]